# plsql comparing table and view

Tags: oracle

I need to get comparison of columns between table and a view i choose to see if there are matching columns.(in PLSQL)
The columns that don't match need to be outputed as: column1 in view1 is missing in table1 etc.
This is so far i have done, but it gives me an error:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c_col
IS
SELECT T.TABLE_NAME,
T.COLUMN_NAME,
V.TABLE_NAME,
V.COLUMN_NAME
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS T
FULL JOIN ALL_TAB_COLUMNS V
ON T.column_name=V.column_NAME
AND v.table_name='EMP_V'
AND v.owner     ='HR'
WHERE T. OWNER  ='HR'
and T.TABLE_NAME='EMPLOYEES';
v_table c_col%rowtype;
begin
OPEN C_col;
LOOP
FETCH C_col into V_TABLe;
EXIT when C_col%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_table.table_name||' '||V_table.column_name);
end LOOP;
close c_col;
end;
```

this is the error i keep getting:
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 16, column 13:
PLS-00402: alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names
ORA-06550: line 16, column 13:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 20, column 22:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 20, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 22, column 27:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 22, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: You have two TABLE_NAME and two COLUMN_NAME columns in one SELECT. Use column aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, for the error cause see the @Multisync comment

```
declare
   cursor c_col is
      select T.TABLE_NAME, T.COLUMN_NAME, V.TABLE_NAME VIEW_NAME,
             V.COLUMN_NAME VIEW_COLUMN_NAME
        from (select *
                 from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS T
                where OWNER = 'HR'
                  and TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES') T
        full outer join (select *
                           from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
                          where owner = 'HR'
                            and table_name = 'EMP_V') V on T.column_name =
                                                     V.column_NAME
       order by t.column_name, v.column_name;
   v_table c_col%rowtype;
begin
   open C_col;
   loop
      fetch C_col
         into V_TABLe;
      exit when C_col%notfound;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad(v_table.table_name || ' ' ||
                                V_table.column_name, 30, ' ') || '|    ' ||
                           v_table.VIEW_NAME || ' ' ||
                           V_table.VIEW_COLUMN_NAME);
   end loop;
   close c_col;
end;
```